# Console background color in a loop is affected by a previous loop

Tags: c#, for-loop, console-application, xamarin-studio

I found a strange bug while working on a c# console application in Xamarin Studio on OS X 10.7.5. If I change the background color in one iteration of the loop, the color will sometimes jump down if there is another loop before this. For example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 18; i++) {
    Console.WriteLine (i);
}
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    if (i == 5) {
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        Console.WriteLine ("green");
        Console.ResetColor ();
    } else {
        Console.WriteLine (i);
    }
}
```

If you run that code, the green background will jump down a line. If you however change the first loop to run 17 times (or fewer) instead of 18, this won't happen anymore. I'm guessing this might be related to the terminal window and you might not be able to replicate it so here's a screenshot of what I get: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgkSp.png

Does anyone know why the line jumps like that and how it can be prevented? Thanks!

Comment: I'm having the same problem on Windows (Visual Studio)

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem and a flush command made it go away.  See if this bit of code will work for you.

```
    public static void WriteInColor(string format, ConsoleColor foreground, ConsoleColor background, params object[] args)
    {
        ConsoleColor prevForeground = Console.ForegroundColor;
        ConsoleColor prevBackground = Console.BackgroundColor;
        Console.ForegroundColor = foreground;
        Console.BackgroundColor = background;
        Console.Write(format, args);
        Console.ForegroundColor = prevForeground;
        Console.BackgroundColor = prevBackground;
        Console.Out.Flush();
    }
```

Comment: You won't get much out of flushing it besides you might change the timing slightly: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/__consolestream.cs,109

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void WriteInColor(object args, ConsoleColor? foreground = null, ConsoleColor? background = null)
{
    ConsoleColor prevForeground = Console.ForegroundColor;
    ConsoleColor prevBackground = Console.BackgroundColor;
    Console.ForegroundColor = foreground.HasValue ? (ConsoleColor)foreground : prevForeground;
    Console.BackgroundColor = background.HasValue ? (ConsoleColor)background : prevBackground; ;
    Console.Write(args);
    Console.ForegroundColor = prevForeground;
    Console.BackgroundColor = prevBackground;
    Console.Out.Flush();
}
```